# In React, is there a good way to demo "connected components" in Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, mocking, storybook

### Connected Components

In React, I really like writing “connected components” — where each component manages its own local state, data fetching, etc.

For example, a high-level `Search` component could be built from an auto-completing `SearchBar`, a `Results` list, and a `Recommendations` section. Ideally, each of these sub-components manage their own state and data fetching.

```
export function Search() {
  const [ search, setSearch ] = useState('');
  return <>
    <AutoCompleteSearchBar search={search} onChange={setSearch}/>
    <SearchResults search={search}/>
    <SearchRecommendations search={search}/>
  </>;
}

export function AutoCompleteSearchBar({ search, onChange }) {
  const { suggestions } = useFetch('/suggestions', { search });
  return <>
    <input value={search} onChange={e => onChange(e.currentTarget.value)} list="suggestions"/>
    <datalist id="suggestions">{suggestions.map((s, i) => <option key={i} value={s}/>)}</datalist>
  </>;
}

export function SearchResults({ search }) {
  const { results } = useFetch('/search', { search });
  return <>
    {!results ? 'Loading...' : results.join(', ')}
  </>;
}

export function SearchRecommendations({ search }) {
  const { recommendations } = useFetch('/recommendations', { search });
  return <>
    {!recommendations ? 'Loading...' : recommendations.join(', ')}
  </>;
}
```

### Not testable or mockable

One of the biggest problems with this approach, however, is that this makes these components really hard to unit test or to use in Storybook stories.

I would LOVE to be able to write stories for these components, which show the various states like “empty”, “searching”, “error”, and “results”.  It would be like how designers typically show multiple comps depicting each of these states.

### Possible solutions

In [the Storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/workflows/build-pages-with-storybook#mocking-connected-components), I did find some unsatisfactory approaches to mocking these connected components:

1. Just mock network traffic

   - This only handles the mocking of the data, but not the UI state.  Eg. I cannot mock text in the search bar.
2. Disconnect your components; reconnect them using a Context

   - This approach requires SO MUCH overhead, it practically defeats the purpose of connected components.  Every single component will be broken down into 4 parts, the context, provider, consumer, and presentation.  The Providers will have to be added to the top-level page anyway.  This amount of complexity defeats the purpose and simplicity of connected components.

##### So please tell me, is there any better way to demo "connected components" in Storybook stories?

Comment: The `search` state is a UI state. The data comes from the user, why do you want to mock it? About API calls, mocking the network traffic is fine.

Comment: In Storybook, it would be incredible to have control over these "UI states".  Imagine you want to do visual regression testing (Chromatic / Happo), or if you wanted to show the various steps of a user-workflow.